# Exporting distinct names based on same Id

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have one table `myTable` with columns `name`, `Id` and `code`.

Sample data in `myTable` is as below.

```
-------------------------
| name  | Id    | code  |
-------------------------
| XYZ   | A12   |  F1   |
| ABC   | B89   |  F2   | 
| WWW   | A12   |  G1   |
| GGT   | C87   |  G2   |
| NTA   | N33   |  H1   |
-------------------------
```

Expected result is

```
-------------------------
| name  | Id    | code  |
-------------------------
|  XYZ  | A12   |  F1   |
|  WWW  | A12   |  G1   |
-------------------------
```

For more details please check below images.

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What is your question; what have you tried so far?

Comment: And why post the same data in text and image form? Which you appear to have done on many of your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although your question is unclear, a simple `WHERE` clause and `DISTINCT` keyword can solve your problem.

```
WITH uniqueNames AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT name
        FROM myTable
        WHERE id = 'A12'
)
SELECT t1.name, t1.id, t1.code
    FROM myTable t1
INNER JOIN uniqueNames ON uniqueNames.name = t1.names
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, we have thousand of records and I want to see only those matching ID records with distinct name. hope this is better explanation. for example, matching record is ID= A12 and distinct name = xyz and www.

Comment: @Mike I have edited my solution, perhaps this would solve your problem.

Comment: Nope, When you are defining " id='A12' , it will definitely bring the correct result for small table like I showed in my example but we don't know the id numbers because it has thousand of thousand records. However, I want to thank you for your help and time.

Comment: You have to pass your id!! Create a stored procedure with a parameter id. and upon calling that procedure, pass your id. It works like function calling.

Comment: Very close result. Thank you for your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

And why wouldn't you just use this?

```
select name, id, code
from t
where id = 'A12';
```